# Remove li from ul based on custom attribute values with Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, custom-attributes

I have multiple ul's with li's with custom attributes:

```
<ul data-id="1">
  <li data-li-id="1">This</li>
  <li data-li-id="2">That</li>
  <li data-li-id="3">Here</li>
</ul>


<ul data-id="2">
  <li data-li-id="1">This</li>
  <li data-li-id="2">That</li>
  <li data-li-id="3">Here</li>
</ul>
```

and I know the data-id of the list and the data-li-id of the li and I want to remove the li from the list. So far I have:

```
 $("ul[data-id=" + data.listId + "] > li").attr('[data-li-id="' + data.listItemId + '"]').remove();
```

but can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$("ul[data-id=" + data.listId + "] > li[data-li-id=" + data.listItemId + "]").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks ... Tick for being first

Answer (score 5):

Here is the test: http://jsfiddle.net/LFEAs/

```
var listId = 2;
var listItemId = 1;
$("ul[data-id=" + listId + "] > li[data-li-id=" + listItemId + "]").remove();
```

Comment: Thank ... Ron just beat you for Tick

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps http://jsfiddle.net/7fcCH/2/

```
$('ul[data-id='+ data.listId +'] li[data-li-id=' + data.listItemId + ']').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks ... Ron beat you by 2 mins so he will get the tick